# linux - simplify semantic versioning script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have semantic versioning for an app component and this is how I update the major version number and then store it back in version.txt. This seems like a lot of lines for a simple operation. Could someone please help me trim this down? No use of `bc` as the docker python image I'm on doesn't seem to have that command.

This is extracted from a yml file and version.txt only contains a major and minor number. 1.3 for example. The code below updates only the major number (1) and resets the minor number to 0. So if I ran the code on 1.3, I would get 2.

```
- echo $(<version.txt) 1 | awk '{print $1 + $2}' > version.txt
  VERSION=$(<version.txt)
  VERSION=${VERSION%.*}
  echo $VERSION > version.txt
  echo "New version = $(<version.txt)"
```

Comment: It's not *that* many lines, frankly. Most of what worries me about it isn't the number of lines, but the places where the code is ambiguous -- `echo $VERSION`, for example, will treat the unquoted value as subject to string-splitting and globbing.

Comment: Generally speaking, seeking a one-liner at the expense of readability, robustness, &c. is prioritizing the wrong things.

Comment: Show us the how the file looks like  - `version.txt`

Comment: That said, what's with the leading dashes? If this is extracted from a YAML configuration file of some kind, we need to know that.

Comment: And most likely no need for anything but a single `awk` script.

Comment: Is it changing `12.43` into `13`?

Comment: Presumably we need to deal with `12.43.56`, not just `12.43`, if it's really semver.

Comment: BTW, since you're on a slim Docker image, I'm a little surprised you have `$(<version.txt)` -- that means you're on an extended shell (such as bash, not dash/ash/etc as typically found as `/bin/sh` on such platforms).

Comment: ...the goal of simplicity should be correctness. When you're achieving terseness by using ambiguous primitives (that is, components that can do undesired things), that terseness is not helping either simplicity *or* correctness: Your real behavior is not simple (since it includes undesired and unexpected corner cases), or correct.

Comment: I am just using a major and minor number to simplify things. And no @Kusalananda, it would change 12.43 to 13

Comment: Your code looks like it's structured as part of a YAML list. What are you running it through? If it's run as five separate shell invocations, then variables aren't persisted across those commands.

Comment: I am running it through bitbucket-pipelines and the variables seem to persist.

Comment: I would suggest putting a multi-line script as a single list entry, just to be unambiguous (ie. to folks coming from ansible or other tooling where each shell command in a list is run by a separate shell). One dash and space at the front, and then just indent all later lines to start at the same indent level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### About Simplicity

"Simple" and "short" are not the same thing. `echo $foo` is shorter than `echo "$foo"`, but it actually does far more things: It splits the value of `foo` apart on characters in `IFS`, evaluates each result of that split as a glob expression, and then recombines them.

Similarly, making your code *simpler* -- as in, limiting the number of steps in the process it goes through -- is not at all the same thing as making it *shorter*.

---

#### Incrementing One Piece, Leaving Others Unmodified

```
if IFS=. read -r major rest <version.txt || [ -n "$major" ]; then
  echo "$((major + 1)).$rest" >"version.txt.$$" && mv "version.txt.$$" version.txt
else
  echo "ERROR: Unable to read version number from version.txt" >&2
  exit 1
fi
```

---

#### Incrementing Major Version, Discarding Others

```
if IFS=. read -r major rest <version.txt || [ -n "$major" ]; then
  echo "$((major + 1))" >"version.txt.$$" && mv "version.txt.$$" "version.txt"
else
  echo "ERROR: Unable to read version number from version.txt" >&2
  exit 1
fi
```

---

#### Rationale

Both of the above are POSIX-compliant, and avoid relying on any capabilities not built into the shell.

- `IFS=. read -r first second third <input` reads the first line of input, and splits it on `.`s into the shell variables `first`, `second` and `third`; notably, the `third` column in this example includes *everything after* the first two, so if you had `a.b.c.d.e.f`, you would get `first=a; second=b; third=d.e.f` -- hence the name `rest` to make this clear. See [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for a detailed explanation.
- `$(( ... ))` creates an arithmetic context in all POSIX-compliant shells. It's only useful for integer math, but since we split the pieces out with the `read`, we only *need* integer math. See http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arith_expr
- Writing to `version.txt.$$` and renaming if that write is successful prevents `version.txt` from being left empty or corrupt if a failure takes place between the open and the write. (A version that was worried about symlink attacks would use `mktemp`, instead of relying on `$$` to generate a unique tempfile name).
- Proceeding through to the write only if the `read` succeeds or `[ -n "$major" ]` is true prevents the code from resetting the version to `1` (by adding 1 to an empty string, which evaluates in an arithmetic context as 0) if the read fails.

Comment: They seem to remove everything after the last dot.

Comment: If they want to go from `13.2.4` to `14`, then it's just `echo "$((major + 1))" >version.txt`, so even easier. A detailed specification would make it easier to be confident in an answer.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! When I run this in bitbucket pipelines:
          `- IFS=. read -r major rest <version.txt
          - echo "$((major + 1)).0" >"version.txt" && mv "version.txt"`
I get: `mv: missing destination file operand after ‘version.txt’
Try 'mv --help' for more information.` I removed the if else statement as it would have to all go onto one line in a bitbucket pipelines yml file and would have been unreadable

Comment: YAML absolutely does allow multi-line literals. If bitbucket uses a real compliant YAML parser, you absolutely can split your literals across multiple lines.

Comment: ...that said, some of my code was just broken -- please see updates.